# Accessing a USB device under Non - Privilaged user with FTDI2XX Driver

Tags: linux, debian, drivers, usb, devices

I am trying access a USB device using libFtd2xx (Version : libftd2xx.so.1.3.6)driver.

Driver Link : http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX/Linux/ReadMe-linux.txt ...
To test device functionality used **Simple** from example directory and mentioned below are the output during execution.

**Under ROOT**

```
venkat:/opt# ./simple-dynamic
Device 0 Serial Number - 12Z9UXGV
Device 1 Serial Number -
Opened device 12Z9UXGV
```

**Under NON_Privilaged User**

```
venkat@venkat:/opt$ ./simple-dynamic
Error: FT_ListDevices(2)
```

Under ROOT User : Device accessing worked as expected. However, when tried executing it under normal user the device was not accessible.

I believe it is somewhere related to some permission . But not able to get through this.

Strace Diff

**ROOT**

```
  open("/dev/bus/usb/001/005", O_RDWR)    = 10
```

**Normal user**

```
  open("/dev/bus/usb/001/005", O_RDWR)    = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Thing I made sure before running this application:

```
    1. rmmod ftdi_sio (as super user)
    2. chmod 0755 /usr/local/lib/libftd2xx.so.1.3.6
    3. ln -sf /usr/local/lib/libftd2xx.so.1.3.6 /usr/local/lib/libftd2xx.so
```

Tried adding permission to UDEV too:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6014", MODE="0755"
```

Request some guidance in addressing this issue.

Source Sample:

/*
    Simple example to open a maximum of 4 devices - write some data then read it back.
    Shows one method of using list devices also.
    Assumes the devices have a loopback connector on them and they also have a serial number*/

```
/*To build use the following gcc statement 
(assuming you have the d2xx library in the /usr/local/lib directory).
gcc -o simple main.c -L. -lftd2xx -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib
*/


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "../ftd2xx.h"

#define BUF_SIZE 0x10

#define MAX_DEVICES     5



static void dumpBuffer(unsigned char *buffer, int elements)
{
    int j;

    printf(" [");
    for (j = 0; j < elements; j++)
    {
        if (j > 0)
            printf(", ");
        printf("0x%02X", (unsigned int)buffer[j]);
    }
    printf("]\n");
}



int main()
{
    unsigned char   cBufWrite[BUF_SIZE];
    unsigned char * pcBufRead = NULL;
    char *  pcBufLD[MAX_DEVICES + 1];
    char    cBufLD[MAX_DEVICES][64];
    DWORD   dwRxSize = 0;
    DWORD   dwBytesWritten, dwBytesRead;
    FT_STATUS   ftStatus;
    FT_HANDLE   ftHandle[MAX_DEVICES];
    int iNumDevs = 0;
    int i, j;
    int iDevicesOpen;   

    for(i = 0; i < MAX_DEVICES; i++) {
        pcBufLD[i] = cBufLD[i];
    }
    pcBufLD[MAX_DEVICES] = NULL;

    ftStatus = FT_ListDevices(pcBufLD, &iNumDevs, FT_LIST_ALL | FT_OPEN_BY_SERIAL_NUMBER);

    if(ftStatus != FT_OK) {
        printf("Error: FT_ListDevices(%d)\n", (int)ftStatus);
        return 1;
    }

    for(i = 0; ( (i <MAX_DEVICES) && (i < iNumDevs) ); i++) {
        printf("Device %d Serial Number - %s\n", i, cBufLD[i]);
    }

    for(j = 0; j < BUF_SIZE; j++) {
        cBufWrite[j] = j;
    }

    for(i = 0; ( (i <MAX_DEVICES) && (i < iNumDevs) ) ; i++) {
        /* Setup */
        if((ftStatus = FT_OpenEx(cBufLD[i], FT_OPEN_BY_SERIAL_NUMBER, &ftHandle[i])) != FT_OK){
            /* 
                This can fail if the ftdi_sio driver is loaded
                use lsmod to check this and rmmod ftdi_sio to remove
                also rmmod usbserial
            */
            printf("Error FT_OpenEx(%d), device %d\n", (int)ftStatus, i);
            printf("Use lsmod to check if ftdi_sio (and usbserial) are present.\n");
            printf("If so, unload them using rmmod, as they conflict with ftd2xx.\n");
            return 1;
        }

        printf("Opened device %s\n", cBufLD[i]);

        iDevicesOpen++;
        if((ftStatus = FT_SetBaudRate(ftHandle[i], 9600)) != FT_OK) {
            printf("Error FT_SetBaudRate(%d), cBufLD[i] = %s\n", (int)ftStatus, cBufLD[i]);
            break;
        }

        printf("Calling FT_Write with this write-buffer:\n");
        dumpBuffer(cBufWrite, BUF_SIZE);

        /* Write */
        ftStatus = FT_Write(ftHandle[i], cBufWrite, BUF_SIZE, &dwBytesWritten);
        if (ftStatus != FT_OK) {
            printf("Error FT_Write(%d)\n", (int)ftStatus);
            break;
        }
        if (dwBytesWritten != (DWORD)BUF_SIZE) {
            printf("FT_Write only wrote %d (of %d) bytes\n", 
                   (int)dwBytesWritten, 
                   BUF_SIZE);
            break;
        }
        sleep(1);

        /* Read */
        dwRxSize = 0;           
        while ((dwRxSize < BUF_SIZE) && (ftStatus == FT_OK)) {
            ftStatus = FT_GetQueueStatus(ftHandle[i], &dwRxSize);
        }
        if(ftStatus == FT_OK) {
            pcBufRead = realloc(pcBufRead, dwRxSize);
            memset(pcBufRead, 0xFF, dwRxSize);
            printf("Calling FT_Read with this read-buffer:\n");
            dumpBuffer(pcBufRead, dwRxSize);
            ftStatus = FT_Read(ftHandle[i], pcBufRead, dwRxSize, &dwBytesRead);
            if (ftStatus != FT_OK) {
                printf("Error FT_Read(%d)\n", (int)ftStatus);
                break;
            }
            if (dwBytesRead != dwRxSize) {
                printf("FT_Read only read %d (of %d) bytes\n",
                       (int)dwBytesRead,
                       (int)dwRxSize);
                break;
            }
            printf("FT_Read read %d bytes.  Read-buffer is now:\n",
                   (int)dwBytesRead);
            dumpBuffer(pcBufRead, (int)dwBytesRead);
            if (0 != memcmp(cBufWrite, pcBufRead, BUF_SIZE)) {
                printf("Error: read-buffer does not match write-buffer.\n");
                break;
            }
            printf("%s test passed.\n", cBufLD[i]);
        }
        else {
            printf("Error FT_GetQueueStatus(%d)\n", (int)ftStatus); 
        }

    }

    iDevicesOpen = i;
    /* Cleanup */
    for(i = 0; i < iDevicesOpen; i++) {
        FT_Close(ftHandle[i]);
        printf("Closed device %s\n", cBufLD[i]);
    }

    if(pcBufRead)
        free(pcBufRead);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're kind of missing some information! (though it's nice to have code).  What are the permissions (`ls -l`) actually achieved on the device node? If you're not sure what the device node is called, run your code under `strace -e open`. Also note udev rules are not re-applied automatically, `udevadm trigger` might work though the most robust  approach would just be to reboot.

Comment: @sourcejedi added strace info :: Seems /dev/bus/usb/001/005 permission issue . request your views

Comment: The question I asked was **What are the permissions (`ls -l`) actually achieved on the device node?**

Comment: @sourcejedi : (0644 ) crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 5 Sep  9 14:51 /dev/bus/usb/001/006

Comment: ok so the rule you added sadly hasn't changed the mode here - (you will also need to change the ownership (user `root` group `root`) for your user to gain access) - can you confirm whether the rule has had a chance to be applied, as described in my first comment?  Actually, if you can unplug+replug the device, that would do it too...  you don't need any other restart/reload of udev because it watches the rule files using inotify, all it needs is a prod to get it to run the rule.

Comment: @sourcejedi : i am sure rule is executing .But >>below is the rule being executed during device plugging.. **ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",  KERNEL=="ttyUSB*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6014", GROUP="plugdev", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/rmmod.sh 4"** .. This rule is surely removing usbserial driver. But the group is not getting reflected.
 Still it is root:root

Comment: ok noted.  as an aside, it might be better to configure `modprobe.conf` to avoid loading the module using a `blacklist` statement.

Comment: @sourcejedi : You are right i am perfectly searching a way for blocking it via modprobe based VID/PID of the device.. That would be the beast approach

Comment: Usually people disable auto-loading of a module completely, using e.g. the config statement `blacklist ftdi_sio`.  It won't be so easy if what you need is to key off the VID/PID and block the driver binding to those specific devices, while allowing to bind to others.

Comment: Can you clarify what you say about udev rules.  Have you added only one udev rule which includes `KERNEL=="ttyUSB"`, which I would expect not to apply to the device node `/dev/bus/usb/001/006`?  Or do you have two separate rules, one without `KERNEL`?  Apologies for asking so many questions, but I don't know myself exactly how to do what you want.  I'm kind of trying to work out whether the specific docs you've been working from so far gave the right answer and you've missed something, or whether we need to go looking around more to find the answer.

Comment: @sourcejedi : Yes i had 2 different rules earlier.

Comment: @sourcejedi : Even i am little confused in applying rules. I was building rules step by step and First derived a rule to delete _ftdi-sio_ using _rmmod_ via script execution, It shaped up as **ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",  KERNEL=="ttyUSB*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6014", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/rmmod.sh 4"**

Comment: after deriving this rule i was stuck under **Permission issue** for which you enlightened me with proper debugging procedure and to address the permission issue added another rule in udev **SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", MODE="0664", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6014", GROUP="plugdev"** . After deriving RULE 2 : My rule 1 _RMMOD_ is not working. So trying a strategy to fix this with **Single rule**

Comment: @sourcejedi : If you have time would like you to look at this : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305439/blacklisting-removing-driver-for-a-particular-vid-pid