# Blacklisting / Removing driver for a particular VID/PID

Tags: linux, debian, drivers, usb, devices

This is in continuation of my previous problem.
[Accessing a USB device under Non - Privilaged user with FTDI2XX Driver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305013/accessing-a-usb-device-under-non-privilaged-user-with-ftdi2xx-driver)

Here i have 2 usbserial hardware modules and it is provisionised that only one can be used at a time.

```
1. 0403:6014
2. 0403:6001
```

I also wanted to make sure device is R/W accesble to "plugdev" group

For device **0403:6014**, I do not want to use inbuilt usbserial(ftdi_sio) driver. I want to access this device using FTD2XXX library.
and for device  **0403:6001**, I want to use inbulit  usbserial(ftdi_sio) driver. I am trying to find a common way to acheive this.

Trails which I attempted so far. Since,  **0403:6001** device uses inbuilt linux driver, I am trying to remove / blacklist ( **0403:6014** ) driver while loading

1. TRIAL 1

   `ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",  KERNEL=="ttyUSB*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6014", 
   RUN+="/usr/local/bin/rmmod.sh 4", GROUP="plugdev"`

   This removes the loaded FTDI driver, but it does not change the device group from ROOT to PLUGDEV

So address that issue added one more rule line

2. TRIAL 2

   `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", MODE="0664", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6014", GROUP="plugdev"
   ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",  KERNEL=="ttyUSB*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6014", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/rmmod.sh 4"`

   This trial sets my device GROUP as expected to "plugdev", but this does not remove the kernel usbserial module.
3. TRIAL 3

   `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", MODE="0664", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6014", GROUP="plugdev"`

   Added ftdi_sio to  `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` , but this blacklists my  **0403:6001** completely.

   This approach works well for **0403:6014** but this completely obseltes my **0403:6001** device

Request some guidance to fix this issue

Comment: Check out http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165685/how-to-disable-usb-devices-based-on-their-vendor-id-on-gnu-linux.

Answer (score 2):

I came across almost the same issue, and completed the script inspired by sourcejedi. I did not had to pass the device path since udev provides quite a bit of information through environment already (use export > /tmp/vars in case you wonder what your script receives). In particular, I use $DEVNAME which is the device name under /dev (e.g. ttyUSB0).

/etc/udev/rules.d/ftdi.rules

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6014", KERNEL=="ttyUSB*" RUN+="/etc/udev/scripts/unbind_ftdi.sh"
```

/etc/udev/scripts/unbind_ftdi.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

# traverse sysfs to find the USB ID
# of the USB device which is parent/ancestor of ttyUSB*
# something like "1-1.6:1.0"
TTYDEV=$(basename $DEVNAME)
BOUND_DEVICES=/sys/bus/usb/drivers/ftdi_sio/*/
for DEVICE in ${BOUND_DEVICES}; do
    if [ -e $DEVICE/$TTYDEV ]; then
        USBID=$(basename $DEVICE)
        break
    fi
done

echo "$USBID" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/ftdi_sio/unbind
```

Comment: Just stumbled upon USB Interface authorization, which might be useful for this purpose too. I did not try it though. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6UHqtbiJX94 around 20 minutes in.

Comment: `USBID=$(basename $(dirname $(dirname $DEVPATH)))` simpler

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  sysfs docs seem to say you can't remove built-in ID's from a driver (unless you patch the source code).  So you will need to manually [unbind](https://lwn.net/Articles/143397/) the driver each time it auto-binds.  (I believe it's also possible to disable auto-binding for all USB devices, but that sounds like a terrible idea).

You will need to match on the `KERNEL="ttyUSB*"` as well as the USB IDs, in order to act *after* the driver is bound.  Your script will have to find the parent USB device.  I noticed there's a weird  `/sys/bus/usb-serial` as well as `/sys/bus/usb`, I'm just hoping that doesn't get in the way here.

I'm not certain how to fill in the code because I don't know what your `DEVPATH` looks like (and I'm too lazy to write a loop for this).  I expect something along the lines of `USBID=$(basename $(dirname $TTY_DEVPATH))`

```
# udev rule
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6014", KERNEL=="ttyUSB*" RUN+="/usr/local/bin/unbind_ftdi.sh %p"

#!/bin/bash
# unbind_ftdi.sh
TTY_DEVPATH="$1"

# traverse sysfs to find the USB ID
# of the USB device which is parent/ancestor of ttyUSB*
# something like "1-1.6:1.0"
....

echo "$USBID" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/ftdi_sio/unbind
```